# Op-amp subtractor circuit not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, voltage-divider

I'm trying to design a PCB to measure single phase 220V(rms), 50Hz voltage using the resistance divider and op-amp subtractor circuit.

The schematic is shown below: [image]

When I measure the signal across R7(1K) the signal is coming out to be fine but when I try to measure the signal across the output of the op-amp the signal is very noisy and of no practical use.

**The output across R7**
[image]

**The output at op-amp output**
[image]

The op-amp is implementing a subtractor circuit finding the difference of the signals at two ends of R7.

I want to know why if I measure directly across R7 I'm getting the desired waveform but when I'm measuring across the op-amp output it is practically useless.

*The resistances used in this circuit have the tolerance level of 0.1% and Op-amp is LMV641MF/NOPB by TI. The oscilloscope used here is Analog Discovery 2(AD2) and the output of AD2 is visualized using Waveforms software.*

Comment: Compare to Figure 43 from TI datasheet.

Comment: You are using a plug-in SMPS for the op-amp power supply are you not?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm using a charge pump IC to produce -5V from the 5V supply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the GND in your circuit has no physical connection to the PE (earth) i.e. it comes from an isolated supply.

If that's the case then it's normal to get noisy output because neither L nor N are not referenced to any of your nets in your DC circuit (e.g. +5V, -5V or GND). You are trying to take a measurement through parasitics (e.g. `V_ph` is tied to isolated GND via 2M resistance) and you are injecting noise.

A common practice in e-metering industry is to short the DC ground to the L for both voltage and current measurement. But you can short the DC ground to the N then take measurements. Or you can use a 1:1 (or a stepdown transformer across L-N) then short the DC ground to one of the ends of the secondary.

Comment: Sir, I used an op-amp with a GBWP(Gain BW product) factor 10 times smaller than that of the op-amp mentioned in the question and then used an LPF and performed the experiment, and now the waveform is very much clean.
Could it cause any problem in the circuit?